# Print Terminal Output Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to assign the terminal output to a varibale then print it to the screen, using `os.popen()`

For example:

```
import os
output = os.popen("dir")
print(output)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output) answer your question?

Comment: I don't want to use subprocess, is there any other way?

Comment: `os.popen` aready uses `subprocess` - doc: [os.popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen) uses `subprocess.Popen()`

Comment: Do you have to assign it to a variable or just printing it on screen is enough?

Comment: @Jarvis I need to assign it to a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible but you should do it like this:

```
import os
output = os.popen("dir")
preprocessed = output.read()
print(preprocessed)
```